# Prevent browser from storing password if signup failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, user-registration

I have a sign up form with email and password/repeat-password fields, using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery. These get submitted to my API using jQuery `$.post()`.

The issue is that even if the signup fails - for example if the email already exists - Chrome offers to save the password. This is annoying.

How can I prevent Chrome from doing so **only if the signup fails**, but not if it succeeds?

When searching I've only found questions and answers about how to completely disable the feature - but I want it to be disabled **only if the POST failed, not if it was successful**. Also, I do **not** wish to disable the password autocomplete feature.

Comment: Just a guess: if submitting the form results in the same registration form being displayed, it may realize that the registration failed.